# typeerror exception not working

Tags: python, exception, typeerror

I'm trying to complete an exercise asking me to use the TypeError exception in Python to account for strings when integers are required.  The example is simple, I ask the user for two numbers and then add them.  I want to use a try block to handle when the user accidentally puts in a string instead of an int.
What I get back is a ValueError traceback saying something about base of 10.

Here's the code:

```
print ("Give me two numbers, and I'll add them.")
print ("Enter 'q' to quit.")

while True:

    try:
        num1 = input("\nEnter first number: ")
        if num1 == 'q':
            break
    except TypeError:
        print ("Please enter a number not a letter.")
    try:    
        num2 = input("\nEnter second number: ")
        if num2 == 'q':
            break
    except TypeError:
        print ("Please enter a number not a letter.")

    sum = int(num1) + int(num2) 
    print ("The sum of your two numbers is: " + str(sum))
```

Here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chapt10 - files and exceptions.py", line 212, in <module>
    sum = int(num1) + int(num2) 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'd'
```

Comment: when you have an error *always* include the full text of the traceback. If you have sensitive info you can mask *that*

Comment: converting a `str` to an `int` doesn't raise a `TypeError` it only raises a `ValueError` if the string cannot be converted to a valid int.

Answer (score 0):

It's great you already have a `try/except` block, but the problem is the *construct* is not being correctly used. If a letter is entered instead of a number, that will be a `ValueError` not a `TypeError`. That's why you have a `ValueError` being raised by your code when a letter is entered; that exception class is not being handled.

More importantly, the `try` block should actually include the *operation* that is likely to raise the error:

```
print ("Give me two numbers, and I'll add them.")
print ("Enter 'q' to quit.")

while True:
    num1 = input("\nEnter first number: ")
    num2 = input("\nEnter second number: ")
    if num1 == 'q' or num2 == 'q':
        break
    try:
        num1 = int(num1) # casting to int will likely raise an error
        num2 = int(num2)
    except ValueError:
        print ("One or both of the entries is not a number. Please try again")
        continue
    total = num1 + num2
    print ("The sum of your two numbers is: " + str(total))
```

On a side note, using `sum` as the name of variable is not good idea as `sum` is a Python builtin.

Comment: Thank you for that answer Moses, but the exercise is meant to show me how TypeError works not TypeValue.  The code you use makes more sense to me, but I want to know when to use TypeError exception.

Comment: `TypeError` and `ValueError` are just two of many exception types; handling one is the same as handling the other.  Among other things, @MosesKoledoye is telling you that you're trying to capture a `TypeError` but your code is raising a `ValueError`, so it doesn't catch it.  If you want a `TypeError`, an easy one is to try adding an int to a string, e.g. `'a' + 1`